# Laravel return data based on relation result

Tags: php, laravel

**PostController.php**

```
$customers = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('agents:agents.id')->get();
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $customer->calculator = $this->calculator($customer);
        }

        return response()->json($customers, 200 );
```

**Post.php**

```
function agents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agent','files','post_id','agent_id');
    }
```

This return right data, like this:

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "hash": "SqB29tkfm1dwGsXp4ZCV",
    "agents": [{
      "id": 1,
      "pivot": {
        "post_id": 5,
        "agent_id": 1
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "hash": "SqH29tkfm1dwGsXp4ZCV",
    "agents": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGsXp4ZCV",
    "agents": [{
      "id": 1,
      "pivot": {
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "hash": "RqH29tkfm1dwGrXp4ZCV",
    "agents": [{
      "id": 1,
      "pivot": {
        "post_id": 1,
        "agent_id": 1
      }
    }]
  }
]
```

But what I want is return just those data that has empty agents `[]` , in this case, should return just id `4` because agents array is empty. how can I do this?

Comment: Try maybe something like 
```->whereNull('agents')```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$customers = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereDoesntHave('agents')->get();
```

If you want to get the customer who doesn't have agents.
Read more at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 2):

you can use both doesntHave or whereDoesntHave like

```
$customers = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->doesntHave('agents')->get();
```

or

```
$customers = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereDoesntHave('agents')->get();
```